# ajax unpload image and showing img thumb

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to work on an application form that fill information and submit to server, but in the images part i am having a problem. i want to show the user a thumb of the selected img. and that can just happen with uploading the img to the server and give it the path and refresh the control when getting back the url of the img.
I am not using the ajaxupload toolkit or anything, all whtat i am using is a input type file, and c# for the code behind and ajax functions.
i am calling the ajax function with javascript but what should i pass as parameter so i can catch it from the server side, save it and how to return back the url of the saved img . i red lots of articles, most of them uses PHP, or ajaxupload packages, nd i think i can be done without that..surely i dont need a post back at all
regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can send file on server using AJAX, 'cause you don't have access to file system via JavaScript. I don't believe what you're trying to do is possible without Flash or Silverlight. Try SWFUpload, for instance. I was using it on my previous project, and it worked fine for me.

EDIT:
And about returning the URL. SWFUpload lets you to send some parameters along with file. So you could generate GUID (on the server side, then just insert it in JavaScript for SWFUpload as an additonal post parameter) and once SWFUpload finished with uploading image, save it on the server using posted GUID as a name of file. After that you can make AJAX request from JavaScript using the same GUID and ask for uploaded image. Hope this helps.